# Deploy Node app on heroku, start script fail

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mlab

[image: heroku logs] 
These are the logs from heroku after I deployed and the app was build successfully on heroku, but after I open the app, it crashed and I check the log, it show as below. As far as I know there seem to be problems with the start script while I can't seem to find any problem `"start": "node server.js"`, I really don't know what to do now. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Hi, are you pushing your `node_modules` directory to Heroku? Instructions to check for this is here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#don-t-check-in-generated-directories

Comment: If you push your node_modules folder to Heroku, Heroku will try to use the version of bcrypt which was built for your own machine. Since it's running on a different OS, it will display errors.

Comment: Thank you! For some reasons, my .gitingore file doesn't work properly, so I need to remove all the tracked files and add the necessary ones to .gitingore. The problem solved now.